# Цена ниже, чем качество

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Попалась однажды такая странноватая реклама.
С одном стороны, все правильно: цена ниже, качество выше. Но почему это выражение воспринимается так, что, мол, качество низкое, а цена еще ниже?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы хотели сказать: "Наша цена ниже той цены, которая реально соответствует нашему высокому качеству". И чтобы было кратко, выразительно и креативно. Но получилось как всегда. Получилось "низкое качество при очень низкой цене". Лучше бы написать: "Цены ниже, качество выше", хотя это и не так креативно.

Comment: Да! Или хотя бы "Качество выше цены".